# Upgrade ZN416 Radio on a Chip to two Tuned RF Stages

Tags: integrated-circuit, radio, system-on-chip

looking to upgrade this Radio/Circuit to two Tuned Circuits with another ZN416 not shunting RF to ground butsending it to the nextZN416.
Will be usingAntique /Vuntage Components Variometer; Variocoupler;Variable Condenser/Coil Assemblies; individual Variable Condensers & Coils

**They are suggested by the manufacturer of the ZN416e to act as a shunt for high-frequency signals to go to ground, preventing them causing noise in certain parts of the circuit.**

http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/ZN416E-AM-radio-circuit.php

Comment: And you question is...? Also, just too much text and did you copy that from somewhere ? Why? Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: `sending it to the next ZN416` ... how are you planning to do that? ... the output of the first ZN416 is audio

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading the ZN414 to two tuned circuits is not for the faint hearted .Your tuned circuits must track so the stations will be received with reasonably even gain .The sections of a ganged tuning cap are not identical but are good enough for this .Some modern tuning caps intended for superhet use have uneven sections like say 365pF and say 208pF .TRF radio tracks best with even caps and even coils .When I do this I do not use a ferrite rod because the rod could pick up signal from the output of the RF amp and give a radio with lots of birdies.I have used shielded RF coils from Dead MW AM radios .These coils were selected for even inductance .My prototype was birdsnested into an old dead   MW AM car radio that had a 3 gang tuning cap .The AGC on the ZN414 is useless which means that you can not really capitalise on the benefits of the RF stage.So I ditched the ZN414 which is mentioned in www.badbeetles.com.The 2 JFET cascode RF stages made a very good sounding credible car radio .The good sound is due to the lack of sideband cutting giving extended treble response .Many modern car radios on MW AM are very narrow band and sound muffled.Your ZN414 can sound good because it is TRF but if the signal is too low it will be buried in the noise and if it is too high your chip will overload and sound bad .How well your proposed radio will go depends on where you live .Close powerful stations are not good for TRF .When I drive past the 1503 KHz radio sport tower it will break through when I am listening to radio coast music on 1593KHz .We are talking wideband receivers here which are HiFi But there is no free lunch because they also let in more noise .The overall sensitivity of my TRF prototype was about the same as an old 1958 wideband Delco Stude superhet that has one RF stage and One IF stage and an active mixer .The modern nissan leaf car radio was more sensitive .

Comment: @ curd .The 416 is supposed to be a 414 with an audio preamp added so as far as the RF is concerned it is the same .I have only used the old 414 because that is what I have in my junkbax.